# Uncompensated and compensated demand functions

Tags: microeconomics, demand, choice-theory, slutsky-equation

I came across this lecture note online and some of the points below confuse me. I have added the part that confuses me as an image and [here](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/109484/14-03-fall-2010/contents/lecture-notes/MIT14_03F10_lec06.pdf) is the lecture note for further reference, if needed.

[image]

Following are my questions:

1. I think the first bullet tries to convey that the compensated $(h_x)$ and the uncompensated demands $(d_x)$ are equal. But is this true all the time? It only holds when the change in price is infinitesimally small if I understand correctly.
2. What are the arguments of the income $\overline{I}$ function? Is it $I(p_x, p_y)$ or something else?
3. How does the chain rule give $\displaystyle \frac{\partial h_x}{\partial p_x} = \frac{\partial d_x}{\partial p_x} + \frac{\partial d_x}{\partial \color{red}{I}} \cdot \frac{\partial E}{\partial p_x}$ instead of $\displaystyle \frac{\partial d_x}{\partial p_x} + \frac{\partial d_x}{\partial \color{red}{E}} \cdot \frac{\partial E}{\partial p_x}$? Can I please get a mathematical derivation? I vaguely understand that in equilibrium, the expenditure will be equal to the income. But I don't see how that translates to this.